# Run a java application on Windows with case sensitive file system

Tags: java, linux, windows, case-sensitive

I have inherited a very complex Java application that runs one step on Linux and one step on Windows.

I have been asked to get both steps to execute on Windows.

The Linux first step produces a HUGE number of output files and folders where many folder names differ only in case, for instance, **/apath/TOP** and **/apath/Top** and it is expected that the two folders are different folders.

Running the first application step on Windows causes the application to fall over on file system operations like rename.

Running the second step on Linux is not possible because it is using a Java/COM bridge to interact with a Windows program with a Windows COM API.

I have setup a Window VM with the Unix subsystem installed with the hope that I can run the application using case sensitive folder names for it's output.  I did not succeed but I think that it should work.

Can anyone suggest a GOOD way to achieve running a complex Java application that outputs folders with case sensitive names on a Windows machine.

Comment: Is there a strong, justifiable, and convincing reason that you would want to have similarly named directories and files for this project?  Or has it always been like this, and you can't shake up the status quo?

Comment: It has always been like this and the is NO BUDGET to change it.

Comment: That's fair.  I don't think attacking the Java side of things will prove fruitful since you're kind of stuck with whatever file system you're on.  Which one are you running on Windows?  [NTFS *should* be POSIX compliant](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100625) and support case-sensitive files...

Comment: I have my choice of NTFS or ReFS.  It does seem that they CAN be POSIX compliant.  That's why I setup a Windows VM with the UNIX subsystem installed.  It seemed to suggest that I can run a POSIX application and NTFS as a case sensitive file system.  I just do not know how to run a Java application in the Windows Unix subsystem.

Comment: I am going to eventually re-architect the application.  Just not this year and there is business being lost NOW.

Comment: So it seems to me then that the question isn't how to make Java do this, since it's at the mercy of the file system.  You want to know how to make the file system case sensitive.  That sounds like [an appropriate question for Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com).

Comment: You could use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) to call Win32 [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS` (0x01000000). That's case sensitive. To delete a file you can add `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`. Also [`FindFirstFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can specify `FIND_FIRST_EX_CASE_SENSITIVE`. There's also the mostly undocumented native NT system calls (ntdll.dll), which can use case-sensitive `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`.

Comment: I'm deploying to Windows 2012 and SUA is deprecated with Cygwin suggested as a POSIX environment replacement.  I tried running a Windows Java program from a Cygwin command prompt and it has case insensitive file system behavior while I could execute case sensitive file system commands for Cygwin.  Oh well...